# Problem synchronizing C/C++ project in Eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, cluster-computing, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse IDE (Version 2021-09) for Scientific computing with parallel tools platform with a cluster. I'm able to connect to cluster within Eclipse.

Further I have tried to implement a synchronized C/C++ makefile project with remote cluster set up for Linux GCC toolchain. However, the synchronization repeatedly fails between local & remote with Eclipse not being able to write `./ptp-sync/info/exclude` to local. Since sync happens before build that means build is also not happening properly. I'm unable to diagnose what is exactly going wrong.

The following is the error log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ptp.rdt.sync.ui 4 4 2021-11-16 00:24:53.818
!MESSAGE Error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.ptp.rdt.sync.core.exceptions.RemoteSyncException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not write file: C:\Users\RickyH\Documents\Test\.ptp-sync\info\exclude.
    at org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.sync.git.core.GitRepo.uploadFilter(GitRepo.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.sync.git.core.GitSyncService.doSync(GitSyncService.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.sync.git.core.GitSyncService.synchronize(GitSyncService.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.rdt.sync.core.SyncManager$SynchronizeJob.run(SyncManager.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not write file: C:\Users\RickyH\Documents\Test\.ptp-sync\info\exclude.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.Policy.error(Policy.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.transferStreams(FileStore.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.copyFile(FileStore.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.copy(FileStore.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.copy(LocalFile.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.sync.git.core.GitRepo.uploadFilter(GitRepo.java:205)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file
    at org.eclipse.remote.internal.jsch.core.commands.GetOutputStreamCommand$1.close(GetOutputStreamCommand.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.transferStreams(FileStore.java:72)
    ... 8 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ptp.rdt.sync.git.core 4 0 2021-11-16 00:24:53.819
!MESSAGE org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not write file: C:\Users\RickyH\Documents\Test\.ptp-sync\info\exclude.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not write file: C:\Users\RickyH\Documents\Test\.ptp-sync\info\exclude.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.Policy.error(Policy.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.transferStreams(FileStore.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.copyFile(FileStore.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.copy(FileStore.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.copy(LocalFile.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.sync.git.core.GitRepo.uploadFilter(GitRepo.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.sync.git.core.GitSyncService.doSync(GitSyncService.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.sync.git.core.GitSyncService.synchronize(GitSyncService.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.rdt.sync.core.SyncManager$SynchronizeJob.run(SyncManager.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file
    at org.eclipse.remote.internal.jsch.core.commands.GetOutputStreamCommand$1.close(GetOutputStreamCommand.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.transferStreams(FileStore.java:72)
    ... 8 more
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.filesystem 4 272 2021-11-16 00:24:53.819
!MESSAGE Could not write file: C:\Users\RickyH\Documents\Test\.ptp-sync\info\exclude.
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: No such file
    at org.eclipse.remote.internal.jsch.core.commands.GetOutputStreamCommand$1.close(GetOutputStreamCommand.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.transferStreams(FileStore.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.copyFile(FileStore.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.copy(FileStore.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.copy(LocalFile.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.sync.git.core.GitRepo.uploadFilter(GitRepo.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.sync.git.core.GitSyncService.doSync(GitSyncService.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.internal.rdt.sync.git.core.GitSyncService.synchronize(GitSyncService.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.ptp.rdt.sync.core.SyncManager$SynchronizeJob.run(SyncManager.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Comment: Just to be sure, have you tried, logged on as RickyH, to directly open/write a `C:\Users\RickyH\Documents\Test\.ptp-sync\info\exclude` file to check there is nothing wrong with your C: filesystem ?

Comment: @Zilog80 There is no problem with the filesystem. I had checked that before posting the question. There is an exclude file at that location. I have checked.